# Unable to connect to SQL Server Express from Web Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, webserver, remote-access, sql-server-express

SOLVED: Missing knowledge of TPC settings for the SQL Server Express was the problem.

We have a web server with an instance of SQL Server Express running. The SQL server is running as intended.

Since we're planning to move the databases to another server programmatically, I'm trying to do backups via program from another machine. This is my connection string:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=IP\SQLEXPRESS,49170; USER=U; PASSWORD=P";
```

The IP and username/password are correct. TCP is enabled for the SQL Server, the firewall has is configured to allow incoming connections on port 49170.

However, I am not able to connect to the Express. I also tried connecting via SSMS, but no success there, either.

Web server is Windows Server 2008, SQL Server Express is 2014 (v12).

Comment: Are you sure that SQL Server listens the port  49170

Comment: Never heard that anybody was  connecting to sql express from network.  Usually only locally or from local IIS.

Comment: When you encounter issues in any kind of software development and need to ask others for help, the very first thing you should ALWAYS provide is the error message you receive. Without even the most basic of information nobody can really help much.

Comment: @Sergey Good hint. I've tried to configure that via Configuration Manager, however when I change TCP-Port to 49170, the service running the Express won't start when I'm trying to restart .

Comment: @marc_s Yes, SQL Server 2014. I'm sorry, it's been a long day and I'm tired.

Comment: Hope, you took a look the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Sergey It seems as though that was a success. I can now connect, even though having problem with the user, but that's another story. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try pinging and telnetting first

Then my connection would be:

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"DATA SOURCE=IP:49170/SQLEXPRESS;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=U;Password=P"
```

Comment: Thanks, it was actually a problem with the TCP configuration, so it's solved.